# is there any option to moving big files to another folder in Github repository?

Tags: github

My file is a .mat file and because it is big enough (18 m) GitHub says it can't show the file. It also has no edit option. So i can't move it to a new folder. how can I move it?
Thanks

[image: The image in this link shows the problem]

Comment: clone locally, move, commit, push.

Comment: is there any way to do it from the website?

Comment: I don't know of such a way.